# JQuery UI auto-complete is not filtering the response text returned by php file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

JQuery UI auto-complete passed with local array is showing filtered result.

This is the code:

```
var localArray = ["BASIC","C++","Fortran","Haskell","JavaScript","PHP","Scheme"];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: localArray
});
```

But when I passed php file to source tag (which is returning the same array), now auto-complete is showing (whole data) unfiltered result whichever character is pressed (matched or unmatched).

This is the code:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: "PHP_Code/MyAjax.php?page=tut_search_ac"
});
```

Here is PHP File:

```
$query = "SELECT title FROM tutorial";
$rs = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()." in query $query");
if($rs)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        $contents[] = $row['title'];
    }
}

echo json_encode($contents);
```

It always show all the values of array. You can also check it [HERE.](http://samplegame.site88.net/JQuery-AutoComplete/default.htm)

Please give me some solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized the issue. There was nothing actual wrong in the above code but a little lack of concept.

JQuery only filter the array given by JavaScript locally.

But does not filter the response text returned by php/server-side.

Therefore we have to include filtering code in php file. (which is also ideal)

```
$keyward = $_REQUEST['term']; //term is equal to keyword
$query = "SELECT title FROM tutorial WHERE title LIKE '%$keyward%' ORDER BY title";
$rs = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()." in query $query");
if($rs)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        $contents[] = $row['title'];
    }
}

echo json_encode($contents);
```

Please feedback in comments if you consider something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `source` property as a remote resource rather than local requires your data to be in a specific format. Specifically, each item is a JSON object with both `label` and `value` properties. Change your PHP script to output your JSON data like this:

```
[
  { label: "BASIC", value: "BASIC" },
  { label: "C++", value: "C++" },
  { label: "Fortran", value: "Fortran" },
  { label: "Haskell", value: "Haskell" },
  { label: "JavaScript", value: "JavaScript" },
  { label: "PHP", value: "PHP" },
  { label: "Scheme", value: "Scheme" }
]
```

To get this structure from your PHP, you need a PHP array with this format:

```
$contents[] = array( "label" => "BASIC", "value" => "BASIC" );
$contents[] = array( "label" => "C++", "value" => "C++" );
$contents[] = array( "label" => "Fortran", "value" => "Fortran" );
$contents[] = array( "label" => "Haskell", "value" => "Haskell" );
$contents[] = array( "label" => "JavaScript", "value" => "JavaScript" );
$contents[] = array( "label" => "PHP", "value" => "PHP" );
$contents[] = array( "label" => "Scheme", "value" => "Scheme" );

echo json_encode($contents);
```

You can also look here to see how to manipulate jquery ui to fit your data:

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Comment: please give me sample data for php script to generate following formate

Comment: lol -- ok, I'll update my answer. Are there any other projects I can do for you?

Comment: thank you dear @swatkins. I will check it soon and accept your answer.

Comment: same problem existing. now I uploaded. please check this [link](http://samplegame.site88.net/JQuery-AutoComplete/default.htm)

Comment: just checked it - looks like it's working as expected.